# How to fix 'TypeError: Cannot find function insertColumns' in Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, typeerror, google-sheets-macros

I'm fairly new to JS and GS and wanted to create a simple insert at a specific location, but I keep getting this error:

> Cannot find method insertColumnBefore(number,number). (line 34, file "InsertColBalSheet")

I've tried:
 - conversion to a number
 - setting the getSheetByName to array [0] (which causes the subsequent line to fail)

```
function InsertColBalSheet() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("BalanceNew");

    ss.setActiveSheet(sheet)

    var cell = ss.getRange("HY3")
    ss.setCurrentCell(cell);
    ss.getActiveSheet().insertColumnBefore(ss.getActiveRange().getColumn(), 4);
};
```

I'm expecting 4 columns to be inserted at **HY3**, but instead, I get the error stated above.

Comment: `insertColumnBefore` and `insertColumnsBefore` have different function signatures. Make sure you are using the correct one by consulting the Apps Script reference documentation. You can access this documentation via the Help menu or by querying your preferred search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know where to insert, a slightly simpler version:

```
function InsertColBalSheet() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("BalanceNew");
      ss.setActiveSheet(sheet)
       var cell = ss.getRange("HY3")
      ss.setCurrentCell(cell);
ss.getActiveSheet().insertColumnsBefore(233,4);
     };
```

but the key difference is insertColumn`s`Before.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I knew it was something simple, but I didn't think it would be a misspelling. +1 for code reviews.